# What does this scala syntax mean?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Could someone explain what (p: Char => Boolean) means? How can I use such parameter?

```
def search(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean = {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a trivial example of how one would execute `search` with the `Char => Boolean` argument:

```
case class Message(msg: String) {
  def search(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean = {
    msg.exists(p)
  }
}

val isVowel: Char => Boolean = c => "AEIOUaeiou".contains(c)
// isVowel: Char => Boolean = <function1>

Message("abcde").search(isVowel)
// res1: Boolean = true

Message("vwxyz").search(isVowel)
// res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 6):

It means that `p` is a function that takes a `Char` and returns a `Boolean`. For example, if you had some `Char` in a variable called `c`, you could do `p(c)` and the result would be a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

Just google for "scala higher order functions" and you will find plenty of examples.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html

https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/higher_order_functions

https://dzone.com/articles/higher-order-functions-in-scala-1

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Higher-order_functions_1